# SARIMAX vs ARIMA in statsmodels (Python)

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima, sarimax

I am estimating ARIMAX and SARIMAX models (time series analysis), and I have some questions about their Python implementation within the `statsmodels` package.

1. The [ARIMA class](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html) in `statsmodels` is supposed to be able to also deal with SARIMAX models ("*This model is the basic interface for ARIMA-type models, including those with exogenous regressors and those with seasonal components. The most general form of the model is SARIMAX(p, d, q)x(P, D, Q, s).*"). However, `statsmodels` also offers a specialized [SARIMAX class](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX). **What are the differences between the two**? This [FAQ page](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_faq.html) seems to offer some explanations, but I'm not sure I exactly understand the core of the issue.
2. If I run a SARIMAX model in `statsmodels` (with either of the two classes above), and the order of integration *d* is nonzero, **will the exogenous regressors be differenced as well**?
3. Again, if I run a SARIMAX model in `statsmodels` and the order of integration *d* is nonzero, **is the regression of the target variable on the exogenous variables run before or after differencing**? In general, **is it run at the beginning of the estimation procedure**?

Thanks in advance,

Fede